# Audio stopped working and App center got removed

Tags: appcenter, sound

Was trying out the Recipes app by Bart Zaalberg. When I installed it i had one unmet dependency: `json-glib-1.0`.

The way I managed to fix that issue was by installing  `elementary-sdk` through `sudo apt install elementary-sdk`.

This is resulted in my laptop  not recognizing sound output devices and the AppCenter being removed from my computer. There may be other issues, but I haven't found them yet.

Edit: My sound works with a few applications (flash on web, vlc) but not others (youtube, spotify)

How can I resolve this?